# SQL case if column is a date

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out how to determine if a given column is a date. This is for a dynamic sorting function that puts null values, empty strings, and 0 at the bottom of the results. I've run into a problem when sorting by date though as the data type 'date' is not a valid argument for ISNUMERIC. Here is what I have right now

```
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN $FIELD IS NULL THEN 1
    WHEN ISNUMERIC($FIELD) = 0 AND $FIELD = '' THEN 2
    WHEN ISNUMERIC($FIELD) = 1 AND $FIELD = 0 THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END DESC, $FIELD
```

This ORDER BY clause is generated by C# append statements and it works great until I try to sort by a date column. Any ideas on how I can make this work right?

EDIT:
Maybe a better question is to ask how to determine what type of data is contained  in a specific column. The field being sorted by could be a string, number, or date. This code works great for everything except dates because ISNUMERIC throws an error when given a date (the DATE data format in SQL Server) value.

Comment: which db engine are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, DB2 or something else?

Comment: Some sample data and the expected result would really assist here (as well as choosing to tag the question with the db you are using) PLUS we need to know the version of that database e.g. SQL Server 2008 cannot do things that SQL Server 2012 can do

Comment: What does your code have to do with determining whether or not the column is a date?

Comment: It's SQL Server. I'm not sure what version since I don't have direct access to it, but I would guess it's 2012. I do know it on Azure.

Comment: What I need to do is take whatever field is being sorted by (which corresponds to a column in the database) and sort by that field. That much is easy. The part I am struggling with is ensuring all values of NULL, '', and 0 always go at the bottom of the results. 
So, the field could be a string, a number, a varchar, an nvarchar, or a date. The code I have now works great except when sorting by a date field which is represented by the date format in the database because ISNUMERIC throws an error in that case.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Later version give you more tools like TRY_PARSE

Comment: I tried TRY_PARSE but it only takes a string argument. The value that would be the argument in my problem could be any of the following datatypes: nvarchar (object), varchar (string or number), or date (date) ... At least from the error messages I've seen, those are the types being used by the database on the backend.

Comment: And I do not know what exact version of SQL Server, but it does appear to be a recent version.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, but you might be looking for [ISDATE(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql).

Comment: I have tried that and ISDATE is not what I need. It is for checking if a string is a valid date format. I need a way to determine if a column in the database contains dates or numbers or strings and so I can put the NULLs, empty strings, and 0s at the bottom of a sorted list every time.